# Intensity plot in map using googleVis in R

Tags: r, plot, ggmap, googlevis, rmaps

I have a long list (around 900 thousand) of latitude and longitude (please note that these coordinates vary up to 13th decimal places) with category of crime done in this coordinates.

This is snapshot of data

[image: data]

Problem: I want to plot a heat map irrespective of type of crime done using only latitude and longitude. something like this

[image: heatmap]

This is what I have tried using `googleVis`

```
M1 <- gvisMap(df_latlong, "LatLong" , "Category",
          options=list(showTip=TRUE, showLine=TRUE, enableScrollWheel=TRUE,
                       mapType='hybrid', useMapTypeControl=TRUE,
                       width=800,height=600))
plot(M1)
```

[image: map]

But this is something else and it is ignoring most of the data. I have no clue how to do it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: if you have 2 questions, maybe you should do two posts ;)

Comment: I suggest looking at into `library(ggmap)` and `help(ggmap)` - there is a crimes visualization example included in its documentation -- you may want to look at [this PDF](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/ggmap.pdf) as well. I would suggest faceting and then either plotting with bins and/or density estimates. Another alternative would be [this site](http://www.openheatmap.com/)

Comment: @ RajanHave you found a solution in the meantime? I want to do something similar and couldn't find an example so far...

Comment: @PatrickBalada, No Patrick, still I haven't found a solution for it